# Separating Values returned from xpathSApply

Tags: xml, r, xpath, xml-parsing

I have some sample XML data below:

```
xml.sample <-'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Production>
<Item>
<ItemNr>1</ItemNr>
<Category>Processing</Category>
<Processed>
<Dia>325</Dia>
<Log>
<LogKey>1</LogKey>
</Log>
<Log>
<LogKey>2</LogKey>
</Log>
</Processed>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemNr>2</ItemNr>
<Category>NoProcessing</Category>
<NotProcessed>
<Dia>72</Dia>
</NotProcessed>
</Item>
<Item>
<ItemNr>3</ItemNr>
<Category>Processing</Category>
<Processed>
<Dia>95</Dia>
<Dia>100</Dia>
<Log>
<LogKey>1</LogKey> %>% 
</Log>
</Processed>
</Item>
</Production>'
```

I read-in and try to run the following code:

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse(xml.sample, useInternalNodes = T)
root <- xmlRoot(doc)

xpathSApply(root, "//Item/Processed/Dia", xmlValue)
```

and it returns the following:

```
"325" "95"  "100"
```

The following format I would like is such that for each `<Item>` node a `<Dia>` tag(s) is found, store ALL the `<Dia>`values related to that `<Item>` node into a section of a list.

So ideally something like this:

```
dia.list <- vector("list", 2)
[[1]]
[1] "325"

[[2]]
[1] "95"  "100"
```

However, the problem is with xpathSApply, it concatenates all values that fulfill the given *Xpath*, so that you can't distinguish which values are from what node.

Any help on this would be greatly Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with `doc` (and not using the root node at all), you could go down to the "Processed" node(s) first with the `[.XMLNode` convenience accessor.  This separates the nodes into a list. Then we can get the separated values from that.

```
lapply(doc["//Item/Processed"], function(x) {
    if(!length(x <- x["Dia"])) NA else sapply(unname(x), xmlValue)
})
# [[1]]
# [1] "325"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "95"  "100"
```

**Update:** The edited code will produce `NA` for cases where there is no "Dia" node.

Comment: I forgot to add this to my question, but for the case that there is no value of `<Dia>` or simply no `<Dia>` tag, how would you insert `NA` into that position of the list using your function?